# Laravel DOM manipulation to show the view from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to show detailed data using ajax, I managed to send the id to the controller but the return generated from the controller is only shown in the browser preview.

Route:

```
Route::post('/event/show',[EventController::class, 'show'])
```

Controller:

```
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $event = Event::find($request->id);
        
        return view('event_show',compact('event');
    }
```

Ajax:

```
    function showDetailEvent(ids){
    $.ajax({
      url : '{{url('')}}/event/show',
      type : "POST",
      cache: false,
      data : {id:ids,_token:'{{csrf_token()}}'},
      success:function(){

        // the question is right here
        
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Isn't `{{url('')}}` a bit pointless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something with the response so that is has any effect. Just doing an ajax request doesn't do that for you because the browser doesn't know what you want him to do.

```js
function showDetailEvent(ids){
    $.ajax({
      url : '{{url('')}}/event/show',
      type : "POST",
      cache: false,
      data : {id:ids,_token:'{{csrf_token()}}'},
      success:function(res){

        $('.container').replaceWith(res);
        
      }
    });
  }
```

I don't know the DOM from your view so you have to replace `.container` with the selector of the element where you want the content to be in.

Unless you have a reason (specific design pattern) to do so, you don't request HTML via ajax. Ajax requests are more likely to be made to the API to receive JSON that can be interpreted by JavaScript.